# 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found while building Simulator App version with xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I have an app built with `Phonegap` that successfully builds and archives in Xcode IDE, but when i try to make a Simulator App version within console, build fails.

I have already tried to add `"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"` and `"$(CORDOVALIB)/Classes"` to Header Search Paths-s, also have tried to remove and add `ios` platform, tried to update all plugins - nothing worked for me.

Command that I try to execute: `xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator13.2` (this SDK exists).

Xcode version - 11.3.1

Logs (not full because of stackoverflow chars limit, but there are all errors):

```
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator13.2

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
CreateBuildDirectory /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build (in target 'Peero' from project 'Peero')
    cd /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios
    builtin-create-build-directory /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build

CreateBuildDirectory /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build (in target 'CordovaLib' from project 'CordovaLib')
    cd /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
    builtin-create-build-directory /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build

MkDir /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.app (in target 'Peero' from project 'Peero')
    cd /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios
    /bin/mkdir -p /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.app

MkDir /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include/Cordova (in target 'CordovaLib' from project 'CordovaLib')
    cd /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
    /bin/mkdir -p /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include/Cordova

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/all-product-headers.yaml (in target 'CordovaLib' from project 'CordovaLib')
    cd /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
    write-file /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/all-product-headers.yaml

skipped ...

CompileC /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.o /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Peero' from project 'Peero')
    cd /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target i386-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length=114 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY=1 -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/usr/local/lib/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/include -I/ -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/DerivedSources-normal/i386 -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -include /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/11945214074210215168/Peero-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.dia -c /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.m -o /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.o
In file included from /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.m:9:
In file included from /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.h:9:
/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/CDVWKWebViewEngine.h:21:9: fatal error: 
      'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileC /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKWebViewEngine.o /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Peero' from project 'Peero')
    cd /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target i386-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length=114 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY=1 -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/usr/local/lib/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/include -I/ -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/DerivedSources-normal/i386 -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -include /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/11945214074210215168/Peero-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKWebViewEngine.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKWebViewEngine.dia -c /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m -o /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKWebViewEngine.o
In file included from /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m:20:
/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/CDVWKWebViewEngine.h:21:9: fatal error: 
      'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CompileC /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory.o /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Peero' from project 'Peero')
    cd /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target i386-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length=114 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY=1 -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Peero-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/usr/local/lib/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/include -I/ -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/DerivedSources-normal/i386 -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -include /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/11945214074210215168/Peero-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory.dia -c /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory.m -o /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory.o

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/build/Peero.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Peero.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.o /Users/Mark/Documents/coins/ios/platforms/ios/Peero/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix/CDVWKWebViewEngine+FileXhrFix.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pasted `"$(OBJROOT)"` with `recursive` to both `Debug` and `Release` in both `Project` and `Target` Header Search Paths - and it works. Hope it might be useful to any.